# Integrating a conditional CDF WRT another distribution with nested support

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

I am reading [*Inference on Counterfactual Distributions*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.0951.pdf) and my knowledge of distribution functions is rusty.

> Suppose we would like to analyze the wage differences between men and women. Let 0 denote the population of men and 1 the population of women. $Y_j$ denotes wages and $X_j$ denotes job market-relevant characteristics affecting wages for populations j = 0 and j = 1. The conditional distribution functions $F_{Y0|X0} (y|x)$ and $F_{Y1|X1} (y|x)$ describe the stochastic assignment of wages to workers with characteristics x, for men and women, respectively. Let $F_{Y\langle 0 \mid 0\rangle}$ and $F_{Y\langle 1 \mid 1\rangle}$ represent the observed distribution function of wages for men and women, and $F_{Y\langle 0 \mid 1\rangle}$ represent the counterfactual distribution function of wages that would have prevailed for women had they faced the men’s wage schedule $F_{Y0|X0}$

They define $F_{Y\langle 0 \mid 1\rangle}$ as "integrating the conditional
distribution of wages for men with respect to the distribution of characteristics for women"

$$ F_{Y\langle 0 \mid 1\rangle}(y) := \int_{\chi_1}F_{Y_0 \mid X_0}(y \mid x) dF_{X_1}$$

In the continuous case, I interpret this is

$$ \int_{\chi_1}F_{Y_0 \mid X_0}(y \mid x) dF_{X_1} = \int_{\chi_1} F_{Y_0 \mid X_0}(y \mid x) f_{X_1}(x)dx = \int_{\chi_1} \int^y \frac{f_{Y_0,\ X_0}(y_0, x)}{f_{X_0}(x)}\ dy_0\ f_{X_1}(x)  dx $$

They make the assumption that the support of $f_{X_1}$ is a subset of the support of $f_{X_0}$, i.e. $\chi_1 \subseteq \chi_0$

What does it mean to integrate a conditional CDF with respect to the conditioning variable?

Is there any deeper meaning to doing so WRT to a different CDF where supports are nested in this way? One way to interpret the above integral is $\mathbb{E}_{X_1}\left[F_{Y_0 \mid X_0}(y \mid x)\right]$ i.e. the expected conditional CDF over the distribution of characteristics for men. Is this the right interpretation, or is there a deeper step that I'm missing here?

Comment: The way you wrote $F_{Y\langle 0 \mid 1\rangle}(y)$ in the first equation makes it a marginal, not a conditional.

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about the conditional in the integral.